# <link rel="alternate" href="" hreflang="en" />

Tags: hreflang

I've an issue with hreflang tag. I'm working in a multilanguage site that have two languages, italian and english. I'd like to set automatically main page language in english for all the countries different from Italy.

I put this code on main page of my website but it seems doesn't work

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en/index.php" hreflang="en" />
```

Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: try using en-us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea the answer is using “en-us” would work.